# Create JSP file in Eclipse using Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

This is my first time using Eclipse and Tomcat.
I want to add an `index,jsp` file containing the following HTTML/JSP content.

```
<%@ page import java.util.Date()%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Message of the Day Application</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="green">
    <h1 align="center">Welcome to MOTD Application</h1>
    <h1 align="center">Version 2.0</h1>
    <h1>Message of the Day: Cloud Computing is Cooler!</h1>
    <h2>The date and time now is <%= new java.util.Date() %></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
java.util.Date cannot be resolved to a type
```

Error raised for the `java.util.Date()` in the line prior to `</body>`

Comment: Does `<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>` instead of `<%@ page import java.util.Date()%>` work?

Comment: no it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Message of the Day Application</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="green">
    <h1 align="center">Welcome to MOTD Application</h1>
    <h1 align="center">Version 2.0</h1>
    <h1>Message of the Day: Cloud Computing is Cooler!</h1>
    <h2>The date and time now is <%= new Date() %></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Also one more thing here as we have imported java.util.Date class then no need to use fully qualified name while using it. We can use it directly with the class name like this <%= new Date() %>